# Who or what could be considered a MacGuffin in The Hateful Eight?

Tags: the-hateful-eight, macguffin

In The Hateful Eight, can Daisy Domergue be considered a [MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)?

The story is about the attempt to save her, but the "story starter" could be Marquis Warren, because the watcher follows him during the story.

Who can be considered the MacGuffin in the movie? Or isn't there a McGuffin in it?

Comment: I'm not sure something as central to the plot as Daisy can be a MacGuffin. Most MacGuffins *appear* to be a key driver of the action but then prove to be an irrelevance (like the money in Psycho). Daisy is always central to the plot in this movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely it's Daisy.  The entire story revolves around her; first her transport and then her rescue.  You may lose sight of that since Tarantino tends to use overly-verbose dialogue, but all of those characters wouldn't even be in that cabin/store if it weren't for Daisy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's the blizzard, it's what brings them all together and keeps them there.